# How do I get the compiz snow plugin working?

Tags: compiz, 11.10, plugins

i've got some trouble installing the snow plugin in Ubuntu 11.10.

I found some tutorials to build it from git but it won't work for me. Spent all day long to get it run but it won't. So Is there anybody with an answer how to get unsupported compiz plugins, or just the snow plugin run?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is probably not supported for Compiz 0.9.x, from the errors you have been getting.

In a nutshell, you cannot install it in 11.10, unless it is ported to Compiz 0.9.x.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the error message it generated please?

You need to install these packages - using

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-dev compizconfig-settings-manager build-essential libtool libglu1-mesa-dev libxss-dev libcairo2-dev git-core
```

Then you should probably create a director (mkdir) `~\compiz`

Navigate to the directory in terminal and

```
git clone git://anongit.compiz-fusion.org/fusion/plugins/snow
```

Download this file to the correct directory: https://sites.google.com/site/oreaus/snow.tar?attredirects=0

Make sure the directory is now ~\compiz\snow

Execute:

```
make
make clean
make install
```

Open `compizconfig-settings-manager` and activate the plugin.

Comment: Tried lots of times, gettin error of missing 'compiz-bcop' and thats not available for oneiric. Even if i try to build compiz-bcop, "No package 'libxslt' found". Well... thats not available. And so it goes...

Comment: while at last step make install its shows me error `No rule to make target build/snow.lo, needed by c-build-objs.  Stop`.

Comment: instead of compiz-bcop it is now compiz-fusion-bcop