# Xsnow does not work

Tags: xorg

I have installed the old program [`xsnow`](http://dropmix.xs4all.nl/rick/Xsnow/) with Apt. This program is supposed to make snow ([the type of precipitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow)) appear on the desktop. However, running the program does nothing except return the following code:

```
Xsnow-1.42resizeable, December 14th 2001 by Rick Jansen (rja@euronet.nl)
WWW: http://www.euronet.nl/~rja/Xsnow/
```

This is because the program is designed to draw the snow on the *root X window*, as stated on the website:

> **Frequently asked question: I start Xsnow but I don't see any snow?** 
>   Answer: Xsnow makes it snow on the X-window "root" window. That root
>   window is often obscured by desktop managers, to display icons and
>   tools. So, Xsnow works fine, you just cannot see the snow! See the
>   README for details and possible solutions.

I tried it in an Ubuntu 13.10 VM, Kubuntu 13.10 and 14.04, and a Lubuntu Trusty Live USB. It is working in Xubuntu, because in Xfce we see the root X window by default. In chat, someone reported it working in Ubuntu 12.04, but in my Ubuntu 13.10 VM I don't see snow.

The problem is that, as I mentioned, `xsnow` draws solely on the root X Window. The root X window is the "parent" of all the other X windows and is therefore also invisible, because modern desktop environments such as KDE and Unity usually hide the root X window with a desktop effects compositor. So `xsnow` still draws snow, (you can get snatches of it when logging in and out due to graphics fragmentation) it's just not visible. On simpler desktops like Openbox and XFCE, the X window (and thus the snow) are completely visible.

Is there any way to view the root X window activity and thus see the snow?

Comment: It works on XFCE, which is what I use.  Just letting you know.  I'm on 13.10+.

Comment: where there any errors in terminal?

Comment: @hbdgaf Good to know, I was about to send a bug report in to Launchpad to let people know it would need to be removed for non-functionality. Will test with Lubuntu.

Comment: There was/is a [compiz plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Snow) to do the same thing. That one is also kinda old and maybe it is not even working now, but here is the [source](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz-fusion-plugins-unsupported) if anyone wants to try it out. (I won't.)

Comment: Just tried it in an Openbox session... Octal snowflakes...

Comment: `xroach` would be nice too... :-) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105778/have-you-seen-this-cat

Answer (score 8):

Using KDE you can use [kwin-snow-effect](https://launchpad.net/~ivan-safonov/+archive/ppa) package.

How to install:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ivan-safonov/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kwin-effect-snow
```

Then in KDE you can set up the effect from `System Settings` --> `Desktop Effects` --> `All Effects` and activate snow.

You can also use the [Compiz plugin Snow](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Snow), Check how it works on this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le9kYqIAtjY)

I found xwinwrap, that let you stick any app as your desktop background. [Click here to download it](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/shantz-xwinwrap-bzr/), Or [here to read to coder's release note](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/09/03/shantz-xwinwrap.html)

It does not give you access to the root window (which seems difficult on most desktop environments). And this one doesn't work with xsnow but it will work with a lot of other apps...

Comment: Oh no it crashed my desktop! Will try it again.

Comment: Just tried kwin effect a I use KDE. Please check this answer : http://askubuntu.com/a/65522/226084 its about getting compiz snow plugin working

Answer (score 4):

Just did some more testing on 12.04 ( Likely this is not the answer for 13.10, but for those who want this on 12.04)

If in gnome-tweak-tool, under *Desktop* I check *Have file manager handle the desktop.* Then both in Unity and in Unity-2D `xsnow` works. Altough in unity-2d the snow in the air is invisible, only the fallen are visible, but that's because of my graphic card and its driver. In Unity it works perfectly.

If in gnome-tweak-tool I uncheck *Have file manager handle the desktop*, then `xsnow` won't even start and throws an error both in Unity and Unity-2D

Answer (score 4):

I'm a user of *Precise* with *Unity* environment, and had the same problem until executing this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

[image: xsnowSnap]

---

Here's an extract of the *xsnow* man page's notes:

**SGI Irix 5.x**

Silicon  Graphics and Irix 5.x users may not see any snow or Santa at all, as long the desktop icons are visible. To circumvent this problem issue this command:

```
/usr/lib/desktop/telldesktop quit
```

The icons will disappear and Xsnow will work perfectly. To restart the desktop just  start

```
/usr/lib/desktop/startdesktop
```

or  select  *Desk‐top -> Home* Directory from the toolchest.

It's  even  possible to have both - desktop icons and xsnow (and even multiple desks). You need to modify the window manager's resource file *4DWm*, the file *~/.desktop-`hostname`/4DWm*. Example:

- `Global.backgroundDescription:   -execute /etc/killall -TERM xsnow ; /usr/local/bin/xsnow`
- `Desk 1.backgroundDescription:   -execute /etc/killall -TERM xsnow ; /usr/local/bin/xsnow`
- `Desk 2.backgroundDescription:   -execute /etc/killall -TERM xsnow ; /usr/local/bin/xsnow`

Restart the window manager (4Dwm) from the toolchest and Xsnow should appear. What this does is stop the currently running Xsnow and start a new one when you switch to another desktop.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately still no snow in Ubuntu 13.10!

Comment: I am not a Silicon Graphics or Irix user, I'm a Radeon dude using KDE. Also the command resulted in `bash: /usr/lib/desktop/telldesktop: No such file or directory`. Thank you for mentioning that part of the README.

Comment: Now the first command is working, but the second one you provided mysteriously isn't...

Comment: I didn't have much trouble with getting it work.. not sure why, but toggling the desktop icon visibility just worked.. it's not advised to, but I was looking to quickly edit some files so I started nautilus as root with `gksu nautilus` (then I didn't know about the --no-desktop switch, which later too didn't help).. that command also root desktop! _But something went wrong.. terribly.._ (Now can't get compiz to work.. I've tried resetting, reinstalling, and all.. So I can't advise to try that..)

Answer (score 2):

**For gnome** you can just tell it not to handle the desktop

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop" --type bool false
```

---

I had also come across some mention of using [shantz-xwinwrap](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/09/03/shantz-xwinwrap.html) for For Unity Compiz, however, it doesn't seem possible on to use with 13.10's version of unity without more fine-tuned control of xsnow.

That said if you want to give it a try in a terminal execute:

```
wget http://anibg.googlecode.com/files/shantz-xwinwrap_v0.3.deb && sudo dpkg -i shantz-xwinwrap_v0.3.deb
```

Once installed, possible execution of xwinwrap without anibg might look like:

```
nice -n 15 xwinwrap -ni -o 0.90 -fs -s -sp -st -b -nf -- '/usr/games/xsnow'
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with remote display of my home computer otherwise I'd totally be testing this.  I thought I found a command here but it really makes no sense as it called xscrensaver/plasma: http://fsckin.com/2008/04/14/fun-with-xwinwrap-in-compiz-fusion/    it would be sweet if Vdesk worked, but when I installed it in kubuntu and tried to run it nothing happened.

Comment: I'm getting `/usr/lib/xscreensaver/plasma: No such file or directory
        
/usr/lib/xscreensaver/plasma died, exit status 2`

Comment: so close I can taste it; having trouble with xsnow reading the args intended for xscreenwrap - but xscreenwrap is definitely working with xscreensaver on 13.10.

Comment: Yeah I suspect it's only a syntax thing...

Comment: The `--root` and `--windows-id` are not supported arguments by xsnow. Those arguments are from a usage example of xwinwrap with glmatrix which accepts `--root` and `--window-id` as arguments : `xwinwrap -ov -fs -- /usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root -window-id WID` for example will work fine

Comment: @yilmi: indeed, it seems that xsnow already draws on the root window so it would seem safe to assume it doesn't need the -root flag, however -window-id WID doesn't appear in the xscreensaver docs and I'm still trying to figure out exactly what it does and how it differs from the default xsnow setting.

Comment: If one removes the xscreensaver args and run, the code runs fine, but xsnow dosen't overlay the desktop.  However, if the computer is allowed to go into powersave, xsnow breifly appears upon resume.

Comment: matrixgl accepts a window-id as arg, so you can provide your desktop as a window-id... Check here : http://sourceforge.net/p/matrixgl/code/ci/master/tree/src/matrix.c#l176       xsnow do not let you choose specific window and always use root window

Comment: @yilmi I think I understand, but am not 100% sure, does the -root and --window-id WIC command cause glmatirx to run in 2 separate windows? or are there different types of root windows?  Either way it looks like xwinwrap won't help.  :(

Comment: Even if you remove all the options and just do `xwinwrap -- /usr/games/xsnow` you get a (small) window with nothing in it expect a copy of whatever your desktop background looks like.

Answer (score 1):

On a standard 12.04.3 64 bit install, login, have just a terminal window near the bottom of the screen, and start xsnow, which works.  Seems to be a leftover  knowledge of where windows were when xsnow was started, and the snow cutoff still occurs after the window is moved or iconized.  Problems occur when a window is near the top of the screen.  Logout/in clears up old windows positions, so experiment with a fresh login (or maybe X restart).  The default delay of 20 is pretty near the minimum for me, increasing that may make the snow appear too.

---

xsnow options are described in the man pages or with the -h switch.  -delay 30 will make a 30 millisecond delay between updates, instead of the default which is 20.  I find things get flakey at 18, and no snow at 15, so on an otherwise working system, too short a delay breaks things.
For 13.10, there is certainly a difference in the way the "root" windows are stacked up.  The 12.04 unity system has a root, child, grandchild, desktop, great great grandchild which is updates with the snow and works. (see output of

```
 `xwininfo -root -tree`
```

The 13.10 unity system actually updates the root window, and the desktop does not even have a full screen child.  With a debugger, changing the window being updated to the desktop does result in images appearing, but they erase the backgound, so not a good solution.  No other window getting the updates shows anything, so I guess it's a conflict with the unity mechanism, which looks like it does need some change for this to work (since the ideal is not to have to change anything but the xsnow program).

---

Update for 14.04 running Unity
To see Santa, give up on the Unity desktop, and just create another X display without it.  Switch back and forth as needed, or even run programs with the -display :1 to show up on the new display.

First allow anyone to run an X server

```
dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

and set the X access to everyone
Yes you can run with sudo, but then you will have left some root owned files on your desktop, and won't be able to login with the GUI any longer (use a virtual terminal to delete the root owned file if you do that).

Do you have another window manager installed so you can move windows around on your new display (only if you want to run other programs there, don't bother if all you want to do is see Santa.  Even a simple one like twm will do,  choose your favorite one that leaves the root window exposed.

Run the below on a vt to get a full screen xsnow.

```
xinit /usr/games/xsnow -- :1 vt8
```

Switch back to the original display on vt7 with Crtl-Alt-F7
and back to xsnow with Ctrl-Alt-F8

Create xterms from vt7 (original X server on :0)

```
xterm -display :1 &
```

start your window manager on the new display from the new xterm e.g.

```
twm&
```

---

16.04 update:
Many things got broken since 14.04 (see bug #1562219), but you can still run xsnow :

1. If running with an Nvidia video driver, use the nouveau driver. Software Updater/Settings button/ Additional Drivers tab, select nouveau.  reboot just to be sure.
2. Log into a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2) for example
3. xinit /usr/games/xsnow -- :1 vt2
   Or start an xterm, and from it start other things like a window manager, xsnow, etc.  Just don't start unity, it takes over the background.

Merry Christmas to All

Comment: Thanks but moving the terminal window to the bottom of the screen did not work for me.

Comment: It's the no windows near the top that's the key, not even iconized ones.  Try a delay of 30 to see if that helps.  Those two items were the only problems I found.

Comment: How would I do a "delay of 30"? Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of [xsnow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/), running on gnome, kde, fvwm, lcde,and even raspbian: https://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/xsnow/index.html

It is available in Debian, but:

The latest version is available [on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/).

From the website:

> Finally, a working xsnow for Gnome, KDE, etc. Based on the original xsnow-1.42 created by Rick Jansen, after the xsnow-2019 conference in Antas (Spain) we now have available a xsnow that works on many desktop environments, even Raspian. By request of many beta-testers, a graphical front end has been created as well.

Answer (score 1):

just issue

```
sudo apt-get install xsnow
```

then launch  `xsnow`

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 with MATE desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the compile instructions you get:

> For compatibility with virtual window managers Xsnow uses 'vroot.h', an include file that makes X programs compatible
>   with window managers like swm and tvtwm. The complete vroot
>   distribution is available from 'ftp.x.org' in the contrib directory as
>   'vroot.shar.Z'. Vroot was written by Andreas Stolcke
>   , 9/7/90 and is copyright 1991 by Andreas
>   Stolcke, copyright 1990 by Solbourne  Computer Inc.

They seem to have taken vroot.h out of the compiling because it was included for KDE. However, the header still comes with the the latest version:

```
wget http://dropmix.xs4all.nl/rick/Xsnow/xsnow-1.42.tar.gz
```

and unpack it. Open `xsnow.c` and add to a new line after 250 (there were problems when I commented it back in where it was.)

```
#include "vroot.h"
```

Then build (requires `xutils-dev`, `xorg-dev` and `libxpm-dev`) with:

```
xmkmf
make depend
make
```

then (assuming no errors)

```
./xsnow
```

Does that work? The compiled version works here but I am in Gnome, on 12.04, and not on a virtual machine.

Comment: Looks like it compiled ok... but still no snow :\ http://i.imgur.com/Pmd9vOx.jpg

Comment: I had a look at xsnow code and the problem is the way it handle the windows it renders on.