# How can the X root window be seen instead of the Unity desktop?

Tags: unity, xorg, root, desktop-background

I would like to be able to see the X root window instead of the Unity desktop. This could be for the purposes of using such programs as [Xphoon](http://www.acme.com/software/xphoon/), which fill the X root window with graphics. How can Unity be set such that the X root window becomes visible instead of the desktop wallpaper?

Comment: This is probably related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/380498/xsnow-does-not-work --- similar olde code. I tried to get `xroach` working but with no success...

Answer (score 0):

1. install fwm or metacity
2. copy `.xintrc` from `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` to `/home/user/`
3. add line to `/home/user/.xinitrc` as `exec fwm` or `exec metacity`
4. edit `/etc/default/burg` as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
5. restart
6. login with username and password
7. run `startx`

Answer (score 0):

A new version of xroach (baptized: xoachng), also running in Gnome and KDE is available here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xroachng/

BTW, new versions of xsnow and xpenguins are also available:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xpenguins/