# Xdesktopwaves, Xsnow, Xpenguins won't work

Tags: xorg, 14.04

I have installed [Xdesktopwaves](http://xdesktopwaves.sourceforge.net/), [Xsnow](https://janswaal.home.xs4all.nl/Xsnow/), [Xpenguins](http://xpenguins.seul.org/) on Ubuntu 14.04. But they are not working at all. I am using gnome desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380498/xsnow-does-not-work) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105778/have-you-seen-this-cat).

These (old, nice) programs were designed when the root window was a window, DBUS and gsettings where unknown, and the concept of desktop environment was to install `fvwm`. You need to recompile them with tricks and often also then they wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

The reason xsnow-1.42 does not work on modern desktops, is that xsnow-1.42 is using the root-window to paint in, and the modern desktops do not use the root window to show the desktop but use another window. This has been addressed by a [new version of xsnow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/).

Comment: The comment on source forge says something like it compiles but doesn't work?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix try [installing `libxpm-dev` and `libgtk-3-dev`](https://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/content/xsnow/introduction) first. I compiled and run it (`/usr/local/games/xsnow`), but just get the menu without the snowing. Willem (the author) do you know what's happening? Do you have plans to build a deb/snap/appimage/flatpack package?

Comment: @PabloA I live in Edmonton so I can look out the window and see real snow falling. Don't need to have it on a Window on my Desktop :) My comment was for the benefit of others. As far as your suggestion to author (*waves* @ Willem) I think DKMS is easiest like Nvidia does it so he just has to maintain one set of code and it's automatically recompiled for every kernel version by Dell's Kernel Management System (oops I mean "Dynamic" not "Dell" even though they wrote it ;)) This way the author only needs change source code when gnome (or whichever DM) changes something. HTH.

Comment: @Pablo sorry for the late response: is the problem solved? If not: what is the environment: distro and desktop. I suspect that xsnow is snowing in the root window. You could try to 'xsnow -xwindow' and point somewhere on the desktop. Not planning to make snap/appimage/flatpack, but .deb is available on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is already solved, but it didn't work for me, I tried to find a solution, and did it! Try installing IceWM window manager and opening a session of it. Then execute those! They all worked for me and always do!

Comment: Why are you posting in response to a question about a version of Ubuntu that's no longer supported here?

Comment: See answer above. The author is just working on fixing it now. I'm not sure most folks will go through trouble of installing IceWM like you did...