# Running an X application from tty

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, tty, xinit

I've been trying to run an X application (firefox) on tt3 (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) with the following command:

```
 xinit /usr/bin/firefox $* -- :2 vt$XDG_VTNR
```

and all I've been getting is a blank screen.

Killing the tty from a different tty with pkill reveals this line in the xinit/startx dialogue

```
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

Does anyone have a clue why a) it isn't working b) what the correct command is?

I am running Ubuntu  20.04 LTS on a laptop, with an external monitor (the built in monitor is acting wonky and is physically disconnected,) with Nvidia graphics (sadly.)

Comment: Well, tty can't graphics. Its a terminal. You have to switch back to your x-session with Crtl+Alt+F7 (could be also another function key) if you have a running x-session.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/380498/xsnow-does-not-work/393708#393708 but since then the X server has been restricted so more may be needed.  Run  dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
 and set the X access to everyone.  Ensure your $XDG_VTNR is the vt you want, otherwise the syntax looks OK.

Comment: @kanehekilli there is absolutely no reason that tty can't do graphics. As a matter of fact gdm3 (the Ubuntu login manager) runs on tty0. And gnome runs on tty1. So there's that.

Comment: Cool - I certainly did not know this. Thanks for clearing this up. I'd be interested in your solution.

Comment: @kanehill the code above *is* the solution, that's the problem. It should be working. But it's not. All I can think of (dpkg-reconfigure did not work) is switching to the neouovo drivers(however they are spelled.) It won't be the first time nVidia did me in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I switched drivers to the Nouveau open source drivers from the Nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary,tested).

The command was correct and everything runs smoothly with the open source driver.

Pity nvidia does not care one iota about people that bought its product.